# How can I disable adding data if the field is empty

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
'''INSERT INTO
       main_parse_user ("user_id","group_id", "username","bio", "first_name") 
       VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) 
       ON CONFLICT (user_id)
       DO UPDATE SET (group_id,username,bio,first_name) =(EXCLUDED.group_id,EXCLUDED.username,coalesce(main_parse_user.bio, EXCLUDED.bio),EXCLUDED.first_name)'''
```

How can I make the username field so that when adding a new record, make it so that if the value from the loaded request in the username field is empty, just skip this user

I haven't tried anything yet

Comment: Create a check constraint on this column and/or a NOT NULL constraint

Comment: Welcome to SO! *"I haven't tried anything yet"* that's exactly the opposite of what people here expect :) You must add what you've tried so far and all the info necessary to reproduce your environment.